# Rendering problems in xml for admob

Tags: java, android

I was following this tutorial on how to get adMob on your app [Here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start) and
In my xml layout file for my activity I am getting a rendering problem:

```
A <fragment> tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.
- <fragment xetron.cosmicclicker.MyActivity$AdFragment ...> (Pick Layout...)
- <fragment xetron.cosmicclicker.MyActivity$AdFragment ...> (Pick Layout...)
 Do not warn about <fragment> tags in this session
```

Xml layout file for activity below

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">



    <fragment
        android:name="xetron.cosmicclicker.MyActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:name="xetron.cosmicclicker.MyActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />



</LinearLayout>
```

What have I done wrong and how do i fix this?

Comment: are you using android studio ?

Comment: yes im using android studio

Comment: Can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragments try putting this:

tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment_view"

where my_fragment_view is the layout you want to be loaded into the fragment. This is for the viewer only.  I think the graphical view is giving you a tip so it can render more smoothly. tools attribute is for editor only. does not work at run time.

```
 <fragment
        android:name="xetron.cosmicclicker.MyActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment_view"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adFragment" />
```

Comment: you have to create a view for your fragment.  What layout do you want your fragment to show ? enter that instead of my_fragment_view.  A fragment is like a sub activity its usually contains a layout file.

Comment: and after that if you want to really load the layout add:android:name="xetron.cosmicclicker.whatever_myFragment_name_is"

Comment: I changed it to my fragment_ad yet and im getting no rendering errors but im getting an error in my activity where it says setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

Comment: the app just crashes and it leads to the line of code that says SetContentView(R.layout.activity_my)

Comment: can you show the contexts of this activity_my ..is it in the layout folder ?